# Read file contents into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, readfile

On a previous project I was required to read file contents into an array.  Now I have to do the same thing only I have to read the contents into an ArrayList.  A few problems I am encountering is

1. How do I step through the ArrayList adding each item separately?
2. If the file contains more than 10 inputs, it has to exit.  I have tried the following, which does not work properly.

Code:

```
   public static String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    String result = "";
    String line = "";

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    int lineCount = 0;
    String[] numbers;
    while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
        numbers = line.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if(i > 10) {
                System.out.println("The file you are accessing contains more than 10      input values.  Please edit the file you wish to use so that it contains"
                        + "> 10 input values.  The program will now exit.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            matrix[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
        }
        lineCount++;

        result += matrix;
    }
```

Comment: This is the current programming that I have to step through an Array.  My question was being able to step through an arrayList.  I was just showing my background thought process.\

Answer (score 3):

Instead of assigning the line to `array[i]`, simply do `arrayList.add(line)`

If this is not homework, consider using some 3rd party utilities like apache-commons `FileUtils.readLines(..)` or guava `Files.readLines(..)`

Comment: This is for a CS241 lab, so I can't do that.  Just looking for general instruction of how to go about doing this.

Comment: well, then look at the first paragraph.

Comment: Perhaps I am not following Bozho?  In regards to the arrayList.add(line) I am trying to store a String into an Int arrayList.

Comment: exactly. `arrayList` is your `ArrayList` instance, and `line` is the string you are trying to store

Answer (score 2):

The `if` condition will always be `false`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(i > 10) {
        System.out.println("The file you are accessing contains more than 10      input values.  Please edit the file you wish to use so that it contains"
                        + "> 10 input values.  The program will now exit.");
                System.exit(0);
    }
```

To append to an `ArrayList` use its `add()` method.
`ArrayList` has a method `size()` which you could use to determine if the file contained more than ten inputs.

EDIT:

The terminating condition of your `for` loop should be based on `numbers.length`, and not ten.